# Single Page App, div nesting and page refresh issues

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a single page app and ran into certain issues. Will try to be as brief as possible. What we have is:

**TL;DR: How to allow browser refresh, bookmark, copy+paste links in a SPA that nests it's contents.**

User requests are sent to **index.php**, a page which echoes a brief structure if the request is sent through GET:

```
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="Content"></div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
```

Based on the parameters following a GET call, such as `&process=10`, a javascript code is also sent to the client to be eval-ed, this is an HTTP request with certain parameters. Upon firing this HTTP request (which also targets the same index.php, this time via POST though), this same index.php file includes the needed .php classes and they return an XML as a result.

The content of the XML result that gets returned to the client-side is an HTML page structure that would get 'inserted into' a specific destination, let's say into a `content` div.

So for example after the user types in the webaddress, the server would actually handle two requests and the result after both of them are handled is as follows:

```
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="Content">
    <div id="Top"> Images </div>
    <div id="Middle"> Hello World </div>
    <div id="Bottom">
        <button> Load more </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
```

Now, let's say the user presses this button, another AJAX request is fired, requesting let's say process 20. This would, for example return a structure via XML that would get placed inside a `top` div, so the new HTML looks like:

```
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="Content">
    <div id="Top">
        <img src="somesrc">
        <div id="imageGallery"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Middle"> Hello World </div>
    <div id="Bottom">
        <button> Load more </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
```

**Now up until this point everything works fine and marvelous!**

Here is where the issue arises. The `url` at the top, looks somewhat like this:

```
www.sitename.com/index.php?process=20
```

And if the user refreshes the page, an issue arises because a GET request is sent to the index.php, the index returns a simple structure, and then fires a process which **"requires"** a div with `id="Top"` in order to have a place to nest itself, however this div does not exist because, process 10 should have been fired beforehand to 'bring it here'.

How would this be solved properly?

I was thinking of using certain predefined patterns for nesting div's but the complexity of the app and the requirement for it to be able to "nest" even 3-4 levels deep. There is no pattern that would be able to handle that sort of depth, or I don't know one.

What are we doing wrong, there has to be some conceptual mistake here, in a sense that its not how this is suppose to be done.

Comment: Maybe move your ajax code into separate file (like `api.php`), then for `index.php` always return your structure with `process` variable somewhere in your javascript code that will call `api.php` with it?

Comment: ajax code is in a separate file, index just decides which fill it will call based on the parameters. The issue is not all ajax calls can be called without a pre-existing structure for their nesting, and there is no way to guarantee that this structure will exist, actually it will 100% not exist if the user refreshes the page, or sends a link to some other user, bookmarks, etc.

Comment: Essentially any "url operation" breaks the concept. Copy a link and send it to a friend, bookmark the page, refresh. Whatever you do that forces a page to be reloaded would have to go through a process chain to get the structure needed for the current display and that process chain is something that does not exist or rather, we do not know how the chain went.

Comment: So always return your structure when users request index.php and add scripts based on query in URL. So for `index.php?process=20` you'll return your whole page as with no query, but add script like `<script>fetch('api.php?process=20')...</script>` that handles ajax and fills your structure?

Comment: That is what is happening now @Walk, but for `process=20` to be properly handled it requires a `<div id="Top">` which is not present in the structure the `index.php` returns. It was brought there by `process=10`. However I do not know if process 10 is present or needs to be fired upon loading process 20. This is "easy to solve" when nesting is just 1 level deep like in the example here, but when we are talking 3-4 levels and pages that have "overviews" of multiple processes as well as customizable views that can show different things, there are issues.